# Using a relationship filter in code in 2sxc

Tags: 2sxc

I've tried to use a relationship filter in code where I wanted some locations grouped by region, So basically something like:

- Region 1

  - address 1
  - address 2
  - address 3
- Region 2

  - address 4
  - address 5

So basically it should do the same except it would query by region. So this is what I came up with:

```
@{
    var someAddresses = App.Query["FilterAddresses"]["ListContent"];
    someAddresses.Filter = region.RegionName;
    Data.In.Add("someAddresses", someAddresses["Default"]);
}
@foreach (var pc in AsDynamic(someAddresses.List)) {
    <li>@pc.Naam</li>
}
```

However it says:

CS1061: ToSic.Eav.DataSources.IDataStream does not contain a definition for Filter.

So should it be something else?

Answer (score 1):

You don't give us a lot of code to help you...

Here is what is working for me but it's not based on a query. However, it should work:

```
@{
    var organismes = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)AsDynamic(App.Data["Organismes"])
        .Where(m => (m.Montrer == true ));

    var groupements = organismes
        .OrderBy(n => n.Nom)
        .GroupBy(i => i.Nom.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper());
}

@foreach (var grp in groupements)
{
     <strong>@grp.Nom</strong>
     <ul>
        @foreach (var term in grp)
        {
             <li>@var.Nom</li>
        }
     </ul>
}
```

You could probably have something like that:

```
@{
    var someAddresses = (IEnumerable<dynamic>)AsDynamic(App.Query["FilterAddresses"]["ListContent"]);

    var groupedAddresses = someAddresses
        .GroupBy(r => r.Region);

}

@foreach (var region in groupedAddresses)
{
     <strong>@region.Name</strong> //Name of the region, adapt to the real variable
     <ul>
        @foreach (var address in region)
        {
             <li>@address.Street, @address.City(@address.Zip)</li> // each field for each address in each region
        }
     </ul>
}
```

UPDATE: Use the GroupBy on a second object.

Comment: No, didn't work. You can't use GroupBy in 2sxc, so that's not the way to go.

Comment: Ok. So use 2 objects just like I did in my exemple. I updated my example to show that.